# SHA3 hardware implementation

Tags: sha-3, cryptographic-hardware, keccak

I am studying SHA3 in order to create a hardware implementation, preferably in verilog. I have downloaded VHDL reference implementation from https://keccak.team/hardware.html.

The code is great, and the reference document really detailed. However I cannot find any way to understand how the VHDL reference implementation receives the rate r and the capacity c parameters. I have understood the VHDL implementation is common for any Keccak-f[1600] transformation, but I do not understand how the code manages SHA3-256(M) or SHA3-512(M) executions.

In addition, is anyone aware of any additional complete Verilog or VHDL implementation?

Comment: Maybe rate and capacity got hardwired into the implementation of each SHA-3 instance. And this may be a programming / hardware design question suitable for another site.